# trying to loggin to revers.it python

Tags: python, session-cookies

i'm tring to login to https://www.reverse.it without success (i get 403 every time )
this is one of my attempts:

```
#base_url = 'https://www.reverse.it/recent-submissions?filter=file'
base_url = 'https://www.reverse.it'
Login_url = 'https://www.reverse.it/login'
username = 'mymail@gmail.com'
password = 'mypassword'

session = requests.Session()
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) " 
+ "Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0"}


# print session.cookies.get_dict()

def request_to_soup(url):
req = session.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
return soup


soup = request_to_soup(base_url + '/login')
print soup

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get(Login_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))





 #login_request = session.post(Login_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

this is one of the ways that i have tried (i have created)

```
  #    'username': (username),
  #    'password' : (password)
 print "******************************************************************************
     ********"
# print session.cookies.get_dict()

cookies = dict(cookies_are='working')
r = requests.get(Login_url, cookies=cookies)
print r
```

i get `<Response [403]>`
every time 
what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the website does not use HTTPBasicAuth.

Comment: i have tried to use HTTPBasicAuth as you can see at the code , but as you can see i have tryed to use: login_request = session.post(Login_url, data=payload, headers=headers) too

Comment: You may need to use the URL that the login posts to, instead of the URL of the login form itself.

Comment: who can i find the URL?
can you give me an example ?

Comment: (i have checked , the "next hop" is the "https://www.reverse.it"(redirected ) , also tried to authenticate to this URL . same results ...

Comment: i have manage to get 200 OK with the next code: